# Symantec rooted certificates trust and Oracle Java trust store, is Oracle planing to remove trust as well?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, java, code-signing, oracle

We are using Symantec CA rooted certs to sign JARs. Since Google and Mozilla have indicated that they are not trusting Symantec CA, should I be concerned that Oracle will remove trust from Symantec CA roots as well in any JVM updates? Was there any indication of such move?

Oracle page https://java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html mention only TLS server certificates being distrusted. Does this mean that JARs signed by certificates rooted in one of the affected CAs are still OK to be used?

Comment: Related: SO: [*What are the implications of the Symantec CA distrust for code signing certificates?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047136/what-are-the-implications-of-the-symantec-ca-distrust-for-code-signing-certifica)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Oracle JRE and JDK Cryptographic Roadmap](https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html) Symantec Root CAs will be removed in April 2019 release:

```
Date: 2019-04-16
Releases: 12, 11, 8, 7
Action: Distrust TLS server certificates anchored by Symantec Root CAs.
```